# Virtual Machine Host and Guest Nic Share Security Concern

Tags: networking, security, virtualization

I suppose I should start by describing desired end goal of this project...

I'd like to set up my desktop to run as a guest on top of a host OS. It might be a vm or container, or whatever, I haven't settled on that yet. The host would be in charge of a couple things; backing up the guest's Home partition to a second drive is an example. I'd also like it to run an http cache, and to be internet connected in order to receive security updates...

I understand that passing an entire NIC through is one way to provide the VM with internet. However, that means that the host would be unable to cache anything, and that I'd need to add a second NIC to my current set up.

I also understand that hypervisors set up vlans for their guest OS', and act as a router for them. This is acceptable. However, I'd like this to be a transparent process for the guest OS... Essentially meaning no firewall. I don't want to have to ssh into my host every time I want to change a port setting.

I was thinking about setting up the host with two IP addresses. One that it uses for itself, and one that is the external side of the vlan. Traffic that is destined for the host gets passed through a strict firewall, and traffic destined for the guest OS is simply cached, if applicable, and then routed.

Firstly, is this the best way to handle this? If so, is this a secure option? For the host OS, that is. Is it still possible to attack the host OS in such an arrangement? Is the 'virtual switch' and http cache stuff isolated enough?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

EDIT: Oops, I suppose I was being a little vague. The project does use Ubuntu/Canonical products, but I guess this exact question is more of a general issue... Basically, the host OS I plan on using is Ubuntu server. I want to remotely administer it using Canonical's Landscape app via a vpn (that would be the hosts only external connectivity). However, I'd like this to be invisible to the guest OS. Meaning, the guest would access the internet through its local discreet router, etc.

Basically, I have family members that keep asking me to fix their computers. 9 times out of 10 the issue is that they shut it off during an update or installed randsomware, or something like that. I'd like to be able to sit down at my computer, push a couple buttons and get them up running again without having to drive to their house to fix it.

I don't want my host OS getting randsomed as well so I want to double check that such an arrangement doesn't making it vulnerable.

Comment: How does this relate to this site?  You've made no mention of any OS, either host or guest and I see nothing currently on-topic for this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Is this your first server ot VM? Seems so from the types of questions you are asking. ADVICE: 1) Your first setup does not matter too much; after you have done several, then you will have a preference. Until you have a preference, stick to the quite sane and easy defaults. 2) You will likely tear down your first server and redo it within a couple months - take good notes so you can rebuild it easily.

Comment: As for family: Start charging them for support. When my aunt comes over with her Windows laptop, she knows to bring a heaping plate of my favorite cookies. Otherwise, I'm busy.

Comment: I wish I got cookies for it :( Usually they just keep asking how to fix it until I say screw it and I'll do it myself...